# Long text scroll in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, scroll, jframe, jpanel

I am building this program and I would like to have a square area that is scrollable since the text is long. I've tried some methods but it seems to cut out the text out of the length. Could anyone give me a tip on how to do this?

```
package gerador;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.Scrollable;

public class frameMyPasswords extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    frameMyPasswords frame = new frameMyPasswords();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public frameMyPasswords() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);
        
        JTextArea txtField = new JTextArea();
        
        txtField.setLineWrap(true);
        txtField.setEditable(false);
        txtField.setToolTipText("");
        txtField.setBounds(10, 38, 419, 144);
        txtField.setText("LONG TEXT");
        contentPane.add(txtField);
    }
}
```

Comment: Check out `JScrollPane`, and don't set the bounds of the `JTextArea`. Let is keep its preferred size, but inside the `JScrollPane`. That will make the scrollbars adjust as necessary.

Comment: @RobSpoor I have added it and it has worked perfectly, but the scroll button only appears at them bottom, do you know how to solve this

Comment: *but the scroll button only appears at them bottom, do you know how to solve this* - this is the way scroll panes work. Take a look at the scrollpane on this website. you have buttons at the top/bottom to do the scrolling. This is a common look and feel.